# How to create dynamic JSON. Filter data and create appropriate JSON objects key and values pairs

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, object

How  to create dynamic JSON as per input. Filter data and create appropriate JSON objects key and values pairs
Below is the database.
[image]

Below is the code which had tried but won't work...

```
success: function (data) {
    //lenght
    data.value.length
    // console.log(data);
    //HC list JSON
    empData = '[';
    $.each(data.value, function (index, item) {
        var dataLen = data.value.length;

        empData += `{`

        if (item.STATUS == 'Active') {

            if (item.NODE == 'Testing') {
                empData += `"DDM_CO2" : {
                        "DESIGNATION": "${item.DESIGNATION}",
                        "EMPLOYMENT": "${item.EMPLOYMENT}",                     
                        "GENDER": "${item.GENDER}",                     
                        "Name1": "${item.Name1}",
                        "ROLE": "${item.ROLE}"                    
                    },`
            } else if (item.NODE == 'Devlopment') {
                empData += `"GPH" : {
                        "DESIGNATION": "${item.DESIGNATION}",
                        "EMPLOYMENT": "${item.EMPLOYMENT}",                     
                        "GENDER": "${item.GENDER}",                     
                        "Name1": "${item.Name1}",
                        "ROLE": "${item.ROLE}"
                    }`
            }
        }
    });
    empData += ']';
    empData = JSON.parse(empData);
    console.log(empData);
    //HC list JSON END              

},
```

Comment: `console.log` your `data.value` that will helps us to see the data format.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
function (data) {
    //create array to store emp objects
    var empData = new Array();
    $.each(data.value, function (index, item) {

        if (item.STATUS == 'Active') {
            if (item.NODE == 'Testing') {
                //create custom object 
                var emp = {
                    DDM_CO2: {
                        DESIGNATION: item.DESIGNATION,
                        EMPLOYMENT: item.EMPLOYMENT
                        //etc: item.etc
                        //etc: item.etc
                        //etc: item.etc
                    }
                };
                //add to array
                empData.push(emp);
            } else if (item.NODE == 'Devlopment') {
                var emp = {
                    GPH: {
                        DESIGNATION: item.DESIGNATION,
                        EMPLOYMENT: item.EMPLOYMENT,
                        GENDER: item.GENDER,
                        Name1: item.Name1,
                        ROLE: item.ROLE
                    }
                };
                empData.push(emp);
            }
        }
    }
```